# Show href value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code

```
$var = hello;    
echo "<a href='#".$var."' class='test'>Link</a>";
```

and I wanted that when I click on the link the href value shows up inside a div in the same page.

```
<div>
// result "#hello" showing up here
</div>
```

How can I do this ? Should I use POST and GET ?
Can you give me any example ?

Thanks

Comment: show the rendered html.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to set some ID or ClASS for this div, and after use just jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.test').click(function() {
        var attr = $('.test').attr('href');//here you take attribute and insert it into div
     $('#divId').text(attr);
    });
});
```

`<div id="divId"></div>` //here will be your href value

Comment: Is it possible to echo "attr" var inside the div like <?php echo $attr; ?> ?

Comment: Yes, you can. But why you need to do this?

Comment: It's something like a shopping cart. Where you have 5 options as a link and when you click it the href value appear inside the div. But I wanted to know if it's possible to pass attr var from javascript to php. For example, to concatenate another value inside php or use it in other function.

Comment: You use it in other function you can set this into session, but you need to refresh the page to get the value from session, or you can use ajax? and send the value to php file without refreshing page

Comment: @sergio: After running the trail of the copycat, it would now be really important that you do not answer manual-material questions. That are those, most easy and straight forward to answer with obvious material as it would better fit for the documentation of a library or langauge. Otherwise you're only taking care to feed help vampires and you're effectively degrading the usefulness of this website. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: @hakre: I dont understand what bad I have did answered this question. Or you talking about comment beloow, what I have did for OP?

Comment: If you don't understand that, please consider that most of the questions you answer are actually material that is off-topic, too broad, despite on-hold or already even close to delete or off-topic. You should not answer such questions but instead - now as you've got some reputation - step in to vote on questions, esp. those of lower quality, duplication etc. For example: Syntax / Parse Error questions, Questions not asking for a concrete programming Problem. Questions showing live-code just copy and pasted. And all these. More clear?

Comment: Also it helps to take a break from answering questions for a while.

Comment: Now it clear.Ok, maybe it is rigth way

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".test").on('click', function() {
    $("div#target").html($(this).attr('href') );
}
```

where target is the id of your div.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery :

```
echo "<a href='#".$var."' class='test'>Link</a>";

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').click(function(e){//click event of link
      var href = $('.test').attr('href');//get value of href
      $("#my_div").html('href');//show value of href on div
      return false; 
    });
    });
```

Make the id of div :

```
 <div id="my_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can watch the hashchange event like this:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    $('.mydiv').html(window.location.hash);
});

<div class="mydiv"></div>
```